# Error loading shared library in C

Tags: c, shared

I'm trying to use the command:

```
gcc -I${HOME}/usr/include -L${HOME}/usr/lib -lsodium test.c
```

but when I try and run a.out it gives the error:

```
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libsodium.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

but libsodium.so.4 is definitely in the ${HOME}/usr/lib directory. What's going on? test.c is just

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sodium.h"
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{ return (0); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${HOME}/usr/lib
```

first and try again.

That `export ...` will tell loader (ld-linux.so) also search `${HOME}/usr/lib` for shared libraries.

Answer (score 3):

`${HOME}/usr/lib` is not in your runtime library path.

You can bake the path into your executable using the gcc option `-Wl,-rpath,${HOME}/usr/lib` or set the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${HOME}/usr/lib` before executing the program.

`ldd a.out` will tell you if `libsodium` can be found in your runtime library path, and if so, the location of the library.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the runtime linker where to find the .so.  Typically this is done with the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, so you would invoke a.out like so (assuming you're using a bash-like shell):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${HOME}/usr/lib ./a.out`